# Perform internal redirect in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, permalinks, templates

Let say I have an existing page named "bar", e.g. http://www.example.com/bar

I want to write a plugin, which when called, will load the content exactly same as bar (not just post_content, but the whole page such as menu, sidebar and footer)

Something like..

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/foo') {
  // Perform internal redirect to /bar
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: When do you want it to load the page? On plugin activation?

Comment: To have something like page alias via plugin code.